# Freemarker csv sorting in asc order and json listing

Tags: json, csv, maven-plugin, freemarker

Recently I played with lazerycode jmeter analysis plugin but no matter how I tried to generate data through freemarker I failed to reach my goals, because for csv ftl I couldn't sort values in asc order or for json ftl I need to delete a comma after list is duplicated to make it work in highcharts, therefore my questions are:

1. For CSV Data, how can I sort this listing in ascending order,especially by samples.minTimestamp:

   ```
   <#ftl/>
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="self" type="java.util.Map<java.lang.String, com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.statistics.Samples>" -->
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="key" type="java.lang.String" -->
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="samples" type="com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.statistics.Samples" -->
   minTimestamp,maxTimestamp,uri,count,average,standarddeviation,errors
   <#list self?keys as key>
   <#assign samples=self(key)/>
   ${samples.minTimestamp},${samples.maxTimestamp},"${key}",${samples.successCount},${samples.average},${samples.standardDeviation},${samples.errorsCount} </br>
   </#list>
   ```
2. For this JSON listing how can I list this block "}," only once (it's after "stdDeviation") , as I need to remove "," after the bracket,otherwise my chart is not rendered and I don't want to go manually to remove the comma on each file :

   ```
   <#ftl/>
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="key" type="java.lang.String" -->
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="self" type="java.util.Map<java.lang.String, com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.parser.AggregatedResponses>" -->
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="requests" type="com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.statistics.Samples" -->
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="aggregatedResponses" type="com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.parser.AggregatedResponses" -->
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="Q_QUANTILES" type="java.lang.Integer" -->
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="K_99_PERCENT" type="java.lang.Integer" -->
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="K_99_PONT_9_PERCENT" type="java.lang.Integer" -->
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="PERCENT_100" type="java.lang.Integer" -->
   <#if !self?keys?has_content>
     "empty": {}
   <#else>
   {
     <#list self?keys as key>
       <#assign aggregatedResponses=self(key)/>
       <#assign requests=aggregatedResponses.duration/>
       <#assign total=requests.successCount + requests.errorsCount/>
       <#assign quantiles=requests.getQuantiles(Q_QUANTILES)/>
       <#if (requests.successCount > 0) >
     "${key}":{
             "y":[0,${quantiles.getQuantile(10*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(20*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(30*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(40*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(50*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(60*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(70*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(80*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(90*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(K_99_PERCENT)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(K_99_PONT_9_PERCENT)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(Q_QUANTILES)?string}],
             "requestStartTime": [${aggregatedResponses.start}],
             "requestEndTime": [${aggregatedResponses.end}],
             "duration": [${requests.duration}],                                               
             "numberOfRequests": [${requests.successCount}],
             "requestsPerSec": [${requests.successPerSecond}],
             "min": [${requests.min}],
             "average": [${requests.average}],
             "max": [${requests.max}],
             "total": [${total}],
             "stdDeviation": [${requests.standardDeviation}]        
           },
       </#if>
     </#list>  
   }     
   </#if>
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions to my questions were resolved internally with a colleague help therefore I'm posting them here:

1. CSV Data sorting:

   ```
   <#ftl/>
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="self" type="java.util.Map<java.lang.String, com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.statistics.Samples>" -->
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="key" type="java.lang.String" -->
   <#-- @ftlvariable name="samples" type="com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.statistics.Samples" -->
   <#assign sorted>
   <#list self?keys as key>
   <#assign samples=self(key)/>
   ${samples.minTimestamp},${samples.maxTimestamp},"${key}",${samples.successCount},${samples.average},${samples.standardDeviation},${samples.errorsCount}
   </#list>
   </#assign>
   minTimestamp,maxTimestamp,uri,count,average,standarddeviation,errors
   <#list sorted?split("\n")?sort as line>
   ${line}
   </#list>
   ```
2. For JSON listing of all elements except the last item "," :

   ```
   -----
             "stdDeviation": [${requests.standardDeviation}]        
       }<#if (key_index+1) < self?keys?size>,</#if>
   </#if>
   </#list>  
   }     
   </#if>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`<#if key_has_next>,</#if>`

This will help you to set "," to all items except last item.
So, your code will look like this

```
<#ftl/>
<#-- @ftlvariable name="key" type="java.lang.String" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="self" type="java.util.Map<java.lang.String, com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.parser.AggregatedResponses>" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="requests" type="com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.statistics.Samples" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="aggregatedResponses" type="com.lazerycode.jmeter.analyzer.parser.AggregatedResponses" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="Q_QUANTILES" type="java.lang.Integer" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="K_99_PERCENT" type="java.lang.Integer" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="K_99_PONT_9_PERCENT" type="java.lang.Integer" -->
<#-- @ftlvariable name="PERCENT_100" type="java.lang.Integer" -->
<#if !self?keys?has_content>
  "empty": {}
<#else>
{
  <#list self?keys as key>
    <#assign aggregatedResponses=self(key)/>
    <#assign requests=aggregatedResponses.duration/>
    <#assign total=requests.successCount + requests.errorsCount/>
    <#assign quantiles=requests.getQuantiles(Q_QUANTILES)/>
    <#if (requests.successCount > 0) >
  "${key}":{
          "y":[0,${quantiles.getQuantile(10*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(20*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(30*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(40*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(50*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(60*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(70*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(80*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(90*10)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(K_99_PERCENT)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(K_99_PONT_9_PERCENT)?string},${quantiles.getQuantile(Q_QUANTILES)?string}],
          "requestStartTime": [${aggregatedResponses.start}],
          "requestEndTime": [${aggregatedResponses.end}],
          "duration": [${requests.duration}],                                               
          "numberOfRequests": [${requests.successCount}],
          "requestsPerSec": [${requests.successPerSecond}],
          "min": [${requests.min}],
          "average": [${requests.average}],
          "max": [${requests.max}],
          "total": [${total}],
          "stdDeviation": [${requests.standardDeviation}]        
        }<#if key_has_next>,</#if>
    </#if>
  </#list>  
}     
</#if>
```

Comment: I found the solutions to my questions, internally, with the help a colleague.I tried the same thing like you suggested and is not working.